# Visual studio code refactoring does not seem to work (e.g. rename symbol - f2)

Tags: c++, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, refactoring

So I have just installed vscode on ubuntu at version: 1.27.2. I have installed the extension for c++ as well.

Its all working nicely, except that I cant seem to use the refactor actions. Specifically I want to use the rename symbol (f2).

When I click a variable and press f2 nothing happens. If I do ctrl+shift+r (refactor actions) I always get "no refactorings available".

I checked the key-bindings and it shows for "f2":

- **Command:** Rename Symbol
- **Keybinding:** F2
- **Source:** Default
- **When:** editorHasRenameProvider && editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly

So I checked that the editor is writeable and text has focus - both true. But I am not sure what this editor has rename provider is?

So I need to install something else? - how can I get refactoring working?

**Update**

This has now been implemented in `vscode-cpptools` extension: version [v0.26](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/releases/tag/0.26.0) called "rename symbol".

Comment: There is an [open "Add renaming"](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/296) issue, what makes you think that refactoring is already implemented? Maybe you are mixing Visual Studio with Visual Studio Code?

Comment: @VTT ohh... but I was reading about the "feature" here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/refactoring, I guess it is not implemented for c++ specifically?

Comment: From the page you've linked "Refactorings are provided by a language service and VS Code has built-in support for TypeScript and JavaScript refactoring through the TypeScript language service. Refactoring support for other programming languages is provided through VS Code extensions which contribute language services."

Comment: @VTT ok thanks for the update - I am now following the issue you linked to... but I don't hold my breath!. If you put your comment down as an answer I will upvote : )

Answer (score 2):

Renaming is not currently implemented by the C++ extension, but a preview of the feature will be released next week for our "insiders" (set the `C_Cpp.updateChannel` setting to `"Insiders"` to get it).

Comment: I just came to this question. I don't believe it is working in the latest version. If I press F2 (or 'rename' from the context menu) it simply does a project-wide search/replace all, even replacing part of the name in comments.

Comment: If you are having trouble with the feature, could you please open an issue on GitHub where my team can help you troubleshoot the problem?
https://www.github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues