# vscode "No refactoring available" c++, (with arduino extention)

Tags: c++, linux, arduino, visual-studio-code, refactoring

I'm getting this error message, while I'm programming my Arduino project and pressing `CTRL+SHIFT+R` for refactoring:

> No refactoring available

I'm getting this as well in my *.cpp* files as in my *.ino* or *.h* files. I got the extensions Arduino, C/C++, C++ Intellisense installed and my file programming language is set to C++.
[image: my vscode extensions]

I'm using vscode on Ubuntu 18.10. I installed vscode with [these](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux) instrucitons from the repository and it is updated to the newest version (1.31.0). What am I doing wrong?

Here are some other inforamtions from "about" in vscode:

```
Version: 1.31.0
Commit: 7c66f58312b48ed8ca4e387ebd9ffe9605332caa
Date: 2019-02-06T08:51:24.856Z
Electron: 3.1.2
Chrome: 66.0.3359.181
Node.js: 10.2.0
V8: 6.6.346.32
OS: Linux x64 4.18.0-13-generic
```

I already posted this question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1403874/vscode-no-refactoring-available-with-arduino-extention-c), but I weren't aware of this recommendation before: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new/choose

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, seems like it isn't even implemented yet, so it is not possible.

Sources:

[Visual studio code refactoring does not seem to work (e.g. rename symbol - f2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53097940/visual-studio-code-refactoring-does-not-seem-to-work-e-g-rename-symbol-f2)

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/296 (Closed)

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/2115 (Closed)

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/1162 (Open: Extract method/variable )

### Edit:

Renaming is implemented since C++ tools extention [0.26](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/releases/tag/0.26.0).

Comment: this is really a shame! Its almost 2021

Comment: OK it's now 2021

Comment: Its the middle of 2021

Comment: It is almost end of 2021

Comment: what a shame. 10-2017...04-2022. this is how you end up, when you take open source code and make a closed-source and uncontributable company project out of it. plus the fact, that you have 2 competing IDE products in the market, where one should not have better features or bypass the commercial one.

Comment: it's beginning of 2023

Comment: It's Q2-2023, already

Comment: It's now Q1 2024 and the refactorings are very limited...